# Looping through with double variables

Tags: php

I have two arrays with two sets of values in ($a[] and $b[])
I want to do something like the following:

$a[0] - $b[0]
$a[0] - $b[1]

$a[1] - $b[0]
$a[1] - $b[1]

This will continue until the arrays reach the end. 
So i want a hyphen to seperate the two arrays, with the first array staying the same until the second array has looped through.

I am trying to get this in a dropdown with option value.

How could i achieve this?
I never tried doing any loops with two varaibles like that before, I literally have no idea at all! 
Thankyou

Comment: What's the pattern there? Can't figure it out.

Comment: I want it to loop through the second arrray for every value of the first. Say if the first array had 2 values and the second had 3, you would have 1-1, 1-2, 1-3, 2-1, 2-2, 2-3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would loop the second array ($b) for each value of the first array ($a).

```
foreach($a as $first) {
foreach($b as $second) {
echo $first . '-'. $second;
}
}
```